# Convert RGB image to yuv420 image by matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to convert RGB image to yuv420 image and this is my Matlab code:

```
ColorImageRGB = imread('view1.png');
ColorImageYUV = rgb2ycbcr(ColorImageRGB);

[rows cols d] = size(ColorImageRGB);
dims = [cols rows];
dimsUV = uint8(dims / 2);
Yd = zeros(dimsUV);
UVd = zeros(dimsUV);

Y = Yd';
U = UVd';
V = UVd';
Y = uint8(Y);
U = uint8(U);
V = uint8(V);

%sample:420
for i = 1 : rows
    for j = 1 : cols
        %sample Y in every row
        r = ColorImageRGB(i,j,1);
        g = ColorImageRGB(i,j,2);
        b = ColorImageRGB(i,j,3);
        Y(i,j) = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b + 16;
        %old line : sample 1/2 U
        if mod(i,2) == 1
            index_i = uint8(i / 2);
            index_j = uint8(j / 2);
            U(index_i,index_j) = -0.147 * r - 0.289 * g + 0.436 * b + 128;
        end
        %even line : sample 1/2 V
        if mod(i,2) == 0
            index_i = uint8(i / 2);
            index_j = uint8(j / 2);
            V(index_i,index_j) = 0.615 * r - 0.515 * g - 0.1 * b + 128;
        end
    end
end

filename = 'view1.yuv';
fid=fopen(filename,'w');
count = fwrite(fid,Y','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,U','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,V','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,Y','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,U','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,V','ubit8');
fclose(fid);
```

view1.png：

[image]

When I get the yuv image ,I read it like this（I have tried to read other yuv image,and it this code can work well）:

```
[Y U V] = yuv_import('view1.yuv',[cols rows],2);
rgb=yuv2rgb(Y{1},U{1},V{1});
imwrite(rgb,'test.bmp','bmp');
```

But test.bmp is no the same as view1.png：
[image]

So ,the question is,what is wrong with the code that convert rgb image to yuv image?Thx。

Comment: Are you converting the input to double anywhere? If you don't then matlab will perform all arithmetic in uint8. Try using im2double which scales all values between [0 1]. You can using im2uin8 when you're done. Looking at your code I think your variables r,g,b will all be uint8 I think.

Comment: @jucestain I have change my code:convert Y,U,V to uint8,it looks better but it seems still not right.

Comment: Copy and paste my answer in your script. I just added a "double" around the first line of your code around the imread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ColorImageRGB = imread('view1.png');
ColorImageYUV = rgb2ycbcr(ColorImageRGB);

[rows cols d] = size(ColorImageRGB);
dims = [cols rows];
dimsUV = uint8(dims / 2);
Yd = zeros(dimsUV);
UVd = zeros(dimsUV);

Y = Yd';
U = UVd';
V = UVd';
Y = uint8(Y);
U = uint8(U);
V = uint8(V);

%sample:420
for i = 1 : rows
    for j = 1 : cols
        %sample Y in every row
        r = ColorImageRGB(i,j,1);
        g = ColorImageRGB(i,j,2);
        b = ColorImageRGB(i,j,3);
        Y(i,j) = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b + 16;
        %old line : sample 1/2 U
        if mod(i,2) == 1
            index_i = uint8(i / 2);
            index_j = uint8(j / 2);
            U(index_i,index_j) = -0.147 * r - 0.289 * g + 0.436 * b + 128;
        end
        %even line : sample 1/2 V
        if mod(i,2) == 0
            index_i = uint8(i / 2);
            index_j = uint8(j / 2);
            V(index_i,index_j) = 0.615 * r - 0.515 * g - 0.1 * b + 128;
        end
    end
end

filename = 'view1.yuv';
fid=fopen(filename,'w');
count = fwrite(fid,Y','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,U','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,V','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,Y','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,U','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,V','ubit8');
fclose(fid);

figure(1);
[Y U V] = yuv_import('view1.yuv',[cols rows],2);
rgb=yuv2rgb(Y{1},U{1},V{1});
imwrite(rgb,'test.bmp','bmp'); 
a = imread('test.bmp');
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(a);

ColorImageRGB = double(imread('view1.png'));
ColorImageYUV = rgb2ycbcr(ColorImageRGB);

[rows cols d] = size(ColorImageRGB);
dims = [cols rows];
dimsUV = uint8(dims / 2);
Yd = zeros(dimsUV);
UVd = zeros(dimsUV);

Y = Yd';
U = UVd';
V = UVd';
Y = uint8(Y);
U = uint8(U);
V = uint8(V);

%sample:420
for i = 1 : rows
    for j = 1 : cols
        %sample Y in every row
        r = ColorImageRGB(i,j,1);
        g = ColorImageRGB(i,j,2);
        b = ColorImageRGB(i,j,3);
        Y(i,j) = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b + 16;
        %old line : sample 1/2 U
        if mod(i,2) == 1
            index_i = uint8(i / 2);
            index_j = uint8(j / 2);
            U(index_i,index_j) = -0.147 * r - 0.289 * g + 0.436 * b + 128;
        end
        %even line : sample 1/2 V
        if mod(i,2) == 0
            index_i = uint8(i / 2);
            index_j = uint8(j / 2);
            V(index_i,index_j) = 0.615 * r - 0.515 * g - 0.1 * b + 128;
        end
    end
end

filename = 'view1.yuv';
fid=fopen(filename,'w');
count = fwrite(fid,Y','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,U','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,V','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,Y','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,U','ubit8');
count = fwrite(fid,V','ubit8');
fclose(fid);

[Y U V] = yuv_import('view1.yuv',[cols rows],2);
rgb=yuv2rgb(Y{1},U{1},V{1});
imwrite(rgb,'test.bmp','bmp'); 
a = imread('test.bmp');
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(a);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @XiaJun try again. I reran the code and these are the outputs when ColorImageRGB isn't cast to double, and when it is.